# How to subscribe the big size file? - NATS Streaming subscribe problem

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I am new NATS. 
I just tried to send and receive a text file using NATS-streaming-server examples.

When I send a text file(~9B), it works

---

-Pub
onnecting to cluster 'test-cluster' as client 'cs-publisher'.
Publishing 1 messages on subject foo
  Url: nats://localhost:4222
  Payload is 9 bytes.
Published 1 msgs with acknowldegements in 0.0076917 seconds (130 msgs/second).

-Sub
Connecting to cluster 'test-cluster' as client 'cs-subscriber'.
Receiving 1 messages on subject foo
  url: nats://localhost:4222
received 1 msgs in 6E-07 seconds (1666666 msgs/second).

---

But, when I send a text file(~80MB), the subscribe didn't work.

---

-Pub
Connecting to cluster 'test-cluster' as client 'cs-publisher'.
Publishing 1 messages on subject foo
  Url: nats://localhost:4222
  Payload is 77552640 bytes.
Published 1 msgs with acknowldegements in 1.2574163 seconds (0 msgs/second).

-Sub
Connecting to cluster 'test-cluster' as client 'cs-subscriber'.
Receiving 1 messages on subject foo
url: nats://loaclhost:4222

---

I don't know why subscribe doesn't react. I used same code and just changed the file what I sent.

byte[] payload   = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");

....

string guid = c.Publish(subject, payload, (obj, pubArgs) =>

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

the problem is NATS just supports message of sizes up to 1 MB. 
https://nats-io.github.io/docs/faq.html#is-there-a-message-size-limitation-in-nats

You have 2 solutions to the problem:

1. Use an object store to store large data there and transmit the reference in the message.
2. break up your message into multiple messages. Although I would be very careful here as you do not have guaranteed ordereing and the messages may end up (if they end up) on different subscribers. So this would highly question the use of NATS at all.